# Delay between Scala test classes

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

In Scalatest with SBT as build tool.I am running all tests of a package as sbt "testOnly package.*".I want to give a delay between different classes run of that package via sbt build definition i.e donot want to change the internal classes,how can this be done?

Note-I am already using 
parallelExecution in Test := false in my build definition,but I want to give a delay between different test class executions also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the test-listeners interface:

```
testListeners += new TestReportListener {
  def startGroup(name: String): Unit = println(s"Start Group $name")
  def endGroup(name: String, result: TestResult.Value): Unit =
    println(s"End Group $name (succeeded)")
  //
  def endGroup(name: String, t: Throwable): Unit = 
    println(s"End Group $name (failed)")
  //
  def testEvent(event: TestEvent): Unit = 
    println(s"Test Event: ${event.result}")
}
```

Then either between groups (files) or individual tests, you insert a `Thread.sleep`. Not very elegant, but I guess it will work.